# Implementing: template <ClassDerivingFromBase, Not>

Tags: c++, templates

I'm attempting to overload arithmetic operators for a Python wrapper.

I am wrapping my Python primitives with:

```
class Float : Object { ... };
class Long  : Object { ... };
:
```

I am attempting to:

```
Float F{3.14};
cout << F+3; // <-- overload F+3 by promoting 3, so F+Float{3}
```

Similarly,

```
Long L{100};
cout << L+1; // L+Long{1}
```

In all of these cases, the left operand derives from Object, whereas the right one doesn't.

Is it possible to construct a single templated function that effectively does:

```
template< <DerivedFromBase, Not> 
operator + ( DerivedFromBase der, Not x ) { 
    return der + DerivedFromBase{x}; 
}
```

i.e. It only catches cases where the left operand derives from Object, whereas the right one doesn't.

And it promotes the right operand to the same type as the left.

And then `der + DerivedFromBase{x}` invokes the + operator that will be defined within DerivedFromBase.

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but why do you use initialiser lists in this case?

Comment: so `template<typename T, typename U, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Object, T>::value && !std::is_base_of<Object, U>::value, int> = 0>`? (alternatively, tag dispatch is probably cleaner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `std::enable_if`, `std::is_base_of` and logical operators between results, it is possible to construct a function whose return type is T (and valid) only if your conditions are met:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_base_of<Object, T>::value && !std::is_base_of<Object, U>::value, T
    >::type
operator + (const T& i1, const U& i2) {
    return i1 + T(i2);
}
```

A complete example code then:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct Object {
    virtual ~Object() {}
};

struct Float : public Object {
    constexpr explicit Float(float v) : val(v) {};
    float val;

    Float operator + (const Float& f) const {
        cout << "Float(" << val << ") + Float(" << f.val << ") = ";
        return Float(val + f.val);
    }
};

struct Long : public Object {
    constexpr explicit Long(long v) : val(v) {};
    long val;

    Long operator + (const Long& l) const {
        cout << "Long(" << val << ") + Long(" << l.val << ") = ";
        return Long(val + l.val);
    }
};

template<typename T, typename U>
typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_base_of<Object, T>::value && !std::is_base_of<Object, U>::value, T
    >::type
operator + (const T& i1, const U& i2) {
    cout << "templated ";
    return i1 + T(i2);
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {
    Long L(100);
    cout << (L+1).val << endl;
    cout << (L+L).val << endl;

    Float F(20.0f);
    cout << (F+1).val << endl;
    cout << (F+F).val << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

With output:

```
templated Long(100) + Long(1) = 101
Long(100) + Long(100) = 200
templated Float(20) + Float(1) = 21
Float(20) + Float(20) = 40
```

Comment: This is an alternative on T.C.'s solution with templated function return type. It compiles and runs on gcc 4.9.1.